# Differences in $L$ and $S$, symmetries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, spin-statistics

I have a symmetric wavefunction when $L=0$. There are a lot of proofs to see this, so I understand it.

I have a symmetric wavefunction when 2 particle of $S=1/2$ each, combine in a bound state with $S=1$.
I can see that from young tableaux and I can see it from the combination of particle used.

Now my question is:
If $su(2) \simeq so(3)$, $L$ comes from $SO(3)$ and $S$ comes from $SU(2)$, why do they have different symmetries when $L$ or $S$ are of a given value?